# Creating version independent Outlook add-ins

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

Looking for a library to create outlook add-in's for outlook 2010, 2007 and outlook 2003

Found this http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/video.php which looks very good but also pricey since it's a general purpose library for creating addins for other office products as well

Is there any other library for comparison and hopefully cheaper too ! google search is inadequate with a rather generic name such as outlook add-in library/tool which return results for existing add-ins etc.

thanks

Comment: Googling the actual programming language along with what you want to do usually helps narrow the searches down.

Comment: I assume that what you mean is write one add-in which works for all 3 versions, that is, a version-neutral add-in? Otherwise it wouldn't be that much work to write a 2003 add-in, and a 2007 and higher add-in.

Comment: @Default, you're usually right - ***usually*** being the operative word :) cheers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com). It is a (free) set of version-independent interop assemblies for making Office add-ins targeting different versions.

NetOffice also has some additional assistance for managing the COM references, Intellisense help on each method to show which versions of the Office application support that method, and then some additional tools to manage your multi-version add-in projects.

Comment: looks very good, will take a look, thanks

Comment: That looks very interesting, hadn't heard about it before.

Answer (score 1):

The library I've found most helpful for interacting with Outlook's mail items and such is [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I have made a search and found some interesting starting point.
[Creating an Outlook 2010 Add-In](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194126/Creating-an-Outlook-2010-Add-In)
[Outlook 2007 Add-in Using Microsoft Visual C#.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58238/Outlook-2007-Add-in-Using-Microsoft-Visual-C-NET)
However is not an easy task to be compatible with various version of Outlook

Comment: Creating an addin is pretty basic with vsto, supporting them in the wild with the myriad versions and sp's is a different story ! hence the quest to make life a bit easier :)