# Universal add-in for all Powerpoint versions

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsto, powerpoint, office-addins

I am using Visual Studio 2012, and create an Powerpoint Add-in application. The thing is I do not only want to deploy this application for Powerpoint 2010, but also for Powerpoint 2013. I don't know how to create a such universal add-in in Visual Studio 2012. Could you please help? I am quite new to Office Add-in Programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question about developing version independent Add-ins (the topic is for Outlook, but same rules apply):
[Creating version independent Outlook add-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569948/creating-version-independent-outlook-add-ins)

You basically have two options:

- using [Addin Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/video.php)
- using [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I really appreciate your response. Do you have any comparison between two above options?

Comment: I can't really offer a detailed comparison, especially since I'm more familiar with the Excel development. For us the deciding factors (in favour of Addin express) were things like: addin express also covered UDFs (Excel specific thing), it has a good support behind it and is actively developed (as you can see there is more than a year since the last update of netoffice), and a few other similar reasons. I would say if you can afford Addin express go for it. Otherwise or if netoffice suffices, go for that.

Comment: Thanks Mitja. Your advice is very useful.